# Avoiding constants namespace code duplication

Tags: c++, arduino

I started to dig into Arduino programming, and have a question on code organization in C++.

Currently I'm trying to write my custom library to work with HW262 shield. My draft code works, but I can't wrap my head how to fix an obvious issue with it's structure.

Here is my code:

`hw262_lib.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>


namespace HW262 {

    namespace PINS {  // declared to be available in this file
        const int S1 = A1;
        const int S2 = A2;
        const int S3 = A3;

        // LEDs
        const int D1 = 13;
        const int D2 = 12;
        const int D3 = 11;
        const int D4 = 10;

        // Buzzer (non-active)
        const int LS = 3;

        // On-board LED 4-digit 7-segment display, driven by dual 74HC595D shift registers
        const int SR_DATA = 8;  // SDI (data)
        const int SR_CLOCK = 7; // SFTCLK (clock)
        const int SR_LATCH = 4; // LCHCLK (latch)
    }

    namespace buttons {
        void init() {
            pinMode(PINS::S1, INPUT_PULLUP);
            pinMode(PINS::S2, INPUT_PULLUP);
            pinMode(PINS::S3, INPUT_PULLUP);
        }
    }

    namespace leds {
        void init() {
            pinMode(PINS::D1, OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite(PINS::D1, HIGH);
            pinMode(PINS::D2, OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite(PINS::D2, HIGH);
            pinMode(PINS::D3, OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite(PINS::D3, HIGH);
            pinMode(PINS::D4, OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite(PINS::D4, HIGH);            
        }
    }
}
```

Now, header file `hw262_lib.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef HW262_LIB_H
#define HW262_LIB_H

#include <Arduino.h>

namespace HW262 {
    namespace PINS { // fully redeclared here, to be available in main.cpp :(
        const int S1 = A1;
        const int S2 = A2;
        const int S3 = A3;

        // LEDs
        const int D1 = 13;
        const int D2 = 12;
        const int D3 = 11;
        const int D4 = 10;

        // Buzzer (non-active)
        const int LS = 3;

        // On-board LED 4-digit 7-segment display, driven by dual 74HC595D shift registers
        const int SR_DATA = 8;  // SDI (data)
        const int SR_CLOCK = 7; // SFTCLK (clock)
        const int SR_LATCH = 4; // LCHCLK (latch)
    }

    namespace buttons {
        void init();
    }

    namespace leds {
        void init();
    }
}


#endif
```

... and the `main.cpp` file, where I'm using the library:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "hw262_lib.h"


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    HW262::buttons::init();
    HW262::leds::init();
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(HW262::PINS::D1, digitalRead(HW262::PINS::S1));
    digitalWrite(HW262::PINS::D2, digitalRead(HW262::PINS::S2));
    digitalWrite(HW262::PINS::D3, digitalRead(HW262::PINS::S3));
}
```

As you can see, full content of `namespace PINS` is duplicated in library's `.cpp` and `.h` files.

How it can be avoided?

Comment: In the `hw262_lib.cpp` source file you can `#include "hw262_lib.h"` and get access to all its contents. Including the namespaces, and their contained members.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wow. It wasn't obvious (for a Python developer). Thanks, it worked. Please publish this as an answer, I believe I'm not the only one who struggled with this question.

Comment: Since it is part of your platform's API, use broken braces(`<>`) instead of qouts(`""`).

Comment: @IhorPomaranskyy, it's the same as importing libraries in Python.

Comment: @kiner_shah kind of. I didn't dare to think about the suggested option, because it looked like a circular import for me.

Comment: Your header file guards seem weird. Usually it's `ifndef` followed by `define` and `endif` at the end of file.

Comment: Your include "guards" ensure that a header *can* be included more than once. Look more clisely at examples. (You basically say `defined = True; if defined: ...`, but you should say `if not defined: defined = True ...`)

Comment: @kiner_shah good point, fixed and updated code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include **hw262_lib.h** in **hw262_lib.cpp** so you can access the content of **hw262_lib.h**

Only put the namespace "PINS" containing the variables in the header file like this.

**hw262_lib.h**

```
namespace HW262 {
    namespace PINS {
        const int S1 = A1;
        const int S2 = A2;
        const int S3 = A3;
    }
}
```

Then include the heder file in your .cpp file and you can access the pins in your .cpp file like this

**hw262_lib.cpp**

```
#include "hw262_lib.h"

namespace HW262 {
    namespace buttons {
        void init() {
            pinMode(PINS::S1, INPUT_PULLUP);
            pinMode(PINS::S2, INPUT_PULLUP);
            pinMode(PINS::S3, INPUT_PULLUP);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need to write them again in the .cpp file